# How to call a view through an item on the select menu?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

Here is the view that displays the Select Menu that will call another View according to the selected filter:

```
    <form action="<?= base_url() ?>process/processfilter" method="post" >
                <div class="col-md-2" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Filter</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="situation" required autofocus>                    
                            <option value="All">List All</option> Here I'd like to call another method that has no filter.
                            <option value="Processing">Processing</option>                                                    
                            <option value="Concluded">Concluded</option>
                            <option value="Archived">Archived</option>  
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Function in Controller Class:

```
public function processfilter($situation) {
$this->load->model('ProcessModel', 'processo');
        $dados['process'] = $this->process->getProcess($situation);
if ($this->process->getProcess($situation)) {
$this->load->view('/reports/process', $dados);
  } else {
            redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

Function in Class Model:

```
function getProcesss($situation) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where("situation", $situation); 
    return $this->db->get('process')->result();
}
```

> **Note:** I need to make a filter in the View like those in Excel.

Comment: Can you please add more detail to what you are trying to do and any issues or error codes that you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting any error, I just need no put the select box to make an action when an item is selected. For example: I have a view that show all the cars and inside that view I have a select menu that give an option to choose to show only brand new cars or only used cars. You gotta it?